# MYSQL stored procedure if else dayname

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to Write a stored procedure to find out the joining date of teachers and if it is a Monday it should display Monday else it should display `Weekday`. I am very new in stored procedure how i can display 'weekday? 
I have prepared a code but am geting error.(dat_teacher_doj is in date datatype)

```html
Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE check_date(IN doj date)
BEGIN
select dayname(dat_teacher_doj)as day from tbl_teachers where dat_teacher_doj=doj;
IF day!='Monday' THEN
SET day='Weekday';
END IF
END //
Delimiter ;
```

AM GETTING ERROR: UNKNWN SYSTEM VARIABLE 'day'

Comment: A.) Your call in the last line has a different name than the procedure "check_date" vs "checkdate". B.) Why would you pass in a date string? I could understand passing in a teacher id or something, but not a static date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to DECLARE your variable. Then use SELECT ... INTO after you have declared your variable.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE check_date (IN teacher_id VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE day VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT dayname(dat_teacher_doj) INTO day FROM tbl_teachers WHERE id = teacher_id;
    SELECT CASE WHEN day != 'Monday' THEN 'Weekday' ELSE day END;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When you call your procedure, you need to put quotes around your input date.

```
call check_date('1982-01-11');
```